# Toggle spoiler-like-content with bootstrap button-group using CSS (no JavaScript)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-controls

Instead of horizontal radio buttons, I would like to have a Bootstrap toggleable button-group to show/hide related content without the use of JavaScript.

Essentially, it will become a form consisting of 3-4 questions that will reveal the correct answer/button in the end (there will be 4 answers to choose from).

How can I achieve this in CSS?

```css
#immigrant:checked~.conditional,
#required-2:checked~.conditional #option-2:checked~.conditional {
  clip: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  position: static;
  width: auto;
}

.control:not(:checked)~.conditional,
#immigrant:not(:checked)~.conditional,
#required-2:not(:checked)~.conditional,
#option-2:not(:checked)~.conditional {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form action="">
  <label class="btn btn-primary" for="citizen">
    <input type="radio" name="residency" value="Citizen" id="citizen"> Citizen</label>
  <p class="conditional">Test Paragraph for Citizens - *Needs to be hidden*</p>
  <input type="radio" name="residency" value="Immigrant" id="immigrant">
  <label class="btn btn-primary" for="immigrant">Immigrants</label>
  <p class="conditional">Test Paragraph for Immigrants</p>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yqpudt31/1/

Comment: I have provided a solution some time ago. Please let me know if it fixed your problem or what I can improve.

Answer (score 0):

The markup does not work in the same way you provided it for the other checkbox. You have to actually put that `<p>` inside the `<label>` so that it is a sibling of the `checkbox` in order to apply styles.

This is the closest I could get. It is kinda hacky, but it works. I wonder why you used all these attributes on the elements to hide and show them. All you want is `display: none` and `display: block` to toggle them.

```css
.control:checked~.conditional,
#immigrant:checked~.conditional,
#required-2:checked~.conditional,
#option-2:checked~.conditional {
  display: block;
}

#citizen:checked~.conditional {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 46px;
  color: #000000;
}

.control:not(:checked)~.conditional,
#immigrant:not(:checked)~.conditional,
#required-2:not(:checked)~.conditional,
#option-2:not(:checked)~.conditional,
#citizen:not(:checked)~.conditional {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <form action="">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" for="citizen">
      <input type="radio" name="residency" value="Citizen" id="citizen"> Citizen
      <p class="conditional">Test Paragraph for Citizens - *Needs to be hidden*</p>
    </label>

    <input type="radio" name="residency" value="Immigrant" id="immigrant">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" for="immigrant">Immigrants</label>
    <p class="conditional">Test Paragraph for Immigrants</p>
  </form>
</body>
```